# Using Automator to recall open Windows of (multiple) Applications

Tags: keyboard, automator

I would like to  **assign** numbers to **open Windows** of (multiple) Applications with a keyboard shortcuts like:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (different numbers for different windows)

and then **recall** them (along with their Desktop/space) with a keyboard shortcut like:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Some of the main Applications I use are **iTerm**, **Emacs**, **Chrome**, **Outlook** (Calendar) and Outlook (Inbox).

The specific modifier for each action does not matter much. I used to do this with AutoHotkey in Windows. How can I do this with Mac OS X? I was told Automator  can help with this (IronAHK seems to not be available anymore)

Comment: You know <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>CMD</kbd> are the same?

Comment: open windows?. Which app

Comment: @markhunte The windows would almost always be the same: iTerm, Emacs, Chrome, Outlook (Calendar) and Outlook (Inbox). This will give me a *fast* way of switching between them without having to worry about what Desktop they are in or looking for their icon

Comment: @user815423426 To clarify more: do you mean switch between windows of a given app using a window number short cut or switch between open Apps using a app number short cut. The wording is a big difference to what you may actually want. Can you edit and explain in more detail. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the effectiveness of assigning numbers to the windows,

since I would forget who is who after the third window or after 5 minutes.

I use the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to see the open windows and then select the one I want.

That works showing open windows by application, and to see them within the application like Chrome use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>.

But that's me, so let's hope someone will be kind enough to spend time writing the script for you since you asked so nicely.

This might be also something for you: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11158